# How to concatenate multiple csv files into one based on column names without having to type every column header in code

Tags: python, csv, merge

I am relatively new to python (about a weeks experience) and I can't seem to find the answer to my problem.

I am trying to merge hundreds of csv files based in my folder Data into a single csv file based on column name.

The solutions I have found require me to type out either each file name or column headers which would take days.

I used this code to create one csv file but the column names move around and therefore the data is not in the same columns over the whole DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
def concatenate(indir=r"C:\\Users\ge\Documents\d\de", 
outfile = r"C:\Users\ge\Documents\d"):
    os.chdir(indir)
    fileList=glob.glob("*.csv")
    dfList = []
    for filename in fileList:
        print(filename)
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, header = None)
        dfList.append(df)
        concatDf = pd.concat(dfList, axis = 0)
    concatDf.to_csv(outfile, index= None)
```

Is there quick fire method to do this as I have less than a week to run statistics on the dataset.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When asking question I would suggest you to minimize your problem. You can post two csv files that you want to merge and then we can help you the most. Also post some code that is trying to merge these two files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This might be me being inexperienced in what I am doing but  surely if I am trying to merge around 600 csv files from folder Data then merging just two isnt going to work?

Comment: Yes, but you can apply same mechanism on 600 files.

Comment: The code above merges all csv files into one but doesn't take column name into account. Other code that does requires you to type the csv file name into the code. Wouldn't I have to do that for all 600 if I applied the same mechanism?

Comment: Do all the csvs contain the same columns (same names and same number), but they are just in different order?

Comment: Ok @GerardChurch, check my answer, it should handle these cases (unless I made a stupid typo) and let me know.

Comment: Let's discuss the details under the answer to keep things neat and clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one, memory efficient, way to do that.

```
from pathlib import Path
import csv

indir = Path(r'C:\\Users\gerardchurch\Documents\Data\dev_en')
outfile = Path(r"C:\\Users\gerardchurch\Documents\Data\output.csv")


def find_header_from_all_files(indir):
    columns = set()
    print("Looking for column names in", indir)
    for f in indir.glob('*.csv'):
        with f.open() as sample_csv:
            sample_reader = csv.DictReader(sample_csv)
            try:
                first_row = next(sample_reader)
            except StopIteration:
                print("File {} doesn't contain any data. Double check this".format(f))
                continue
            else:
                columns.update(first_row.keys())
    return columns


columns = find_header_from_all_files(indir)
print("The columns are:", sorted(columns))

with outfile.open('w') as outf:
    wr = csv.DictWriter(outf, fieldnames=list(columns))
    wr.writeheader()
    for inpath in indir.glob('*.csv'):
        print("Parsing", inpath)
        with inpath.open() as infile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
            wr.writerows(reader)
print("Done, find the output at", outfile)
```

This should handle case, when one of the input csvs doesn't contain all `columns`

Comment: Thanks for that @RobinNemeth! I have run the code and have no csv file, is there something that I am doing wrong? It doesn't come up with any errors just StopIteration.

Comment: I should have seen that one coming.Stopiteration is an error. I've added a fix + some print statements for debugging. Can you rerun this now? Also double check all the paths are valid.  If there is an error, post the whole stack trace here, please

Comment: Thanks for fixing. Ran the code and created the csv file fine but has turned 106 columns into 16,000 columns and caused a serious error to crash the programme. Any suggestions as to what has happened? @RobinNemeth

Comment: At this point it would be best if you could edit your original post to include first two or three rows (with the headers) of couple of your csvs

Comment: Funny as when I create a new folder of just 2 csv files and re-run the code then it comes out fine. In regards to the first few rows, there is not enough room on the page to fit all the info. @RobinNemeth

Comment: Is the delimiter `,` correct in all your csvs? At this point I would modify the `find_header_from_all_files` function to go through the csvs in your folder and report how many columns are there in each of the files (hint: append a tuple `(filename, len(first_rows.keys())` to a list and sort it by the number of columns. I suspect there will be one file which misbehaves and ruins everything.

Comment: It's worked! Thanks very much, I think the problem is with Excel not being able to open or handle the file, when I load it into Spyder as a DataFrame is seems to be correct. Thanks again @RobinNemeth

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but this is one of the ways that you can merge your files without giving any column names:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os


def concatenate(indir):
    os.chdir(indir)
    fileList=glob.glob("*.csv")
    output_file = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(filename) for filename in fileList])
    output_file.to_csv("_output.csv", index=False)


concatenate(indir= r"C:\\Users\gerardchurch\Documents\Data\dev_en")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I do need to column headers as I need to know what the data is.